# Usage du conditionnel contrevenant à la concordance des temps

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical, conditionnel

Je voudrais savoir si la phrase suivante est correcte sur le plan grammatical :

> S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, cela pourrait poser problème.

On lit souvent qu'il y a une correspondance obligatoire entre le temps (et le mode) *X* de la subordonnée introduite par *si*, d'une part, et le temps *Y* du verbe de la proposition principale, d'autre part. Par exemple, on peut avoir *X* au présent, puis *Y* au présent ou au futur. Ou bien *X* peut être à l'imparfait et *Y* au conditionnel. En suivant cette règle, on devrait donc avoir

> S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, cela pourra/peut poser problème.

ou

> S'il ne réussissait pas à la joindre, cela pourrait poser problème.

Mais dans *Le Bon Usage* de Grévisse, on donne plusieurs exemples où le non-respect de cette correspondance est justifié en raison d'une nuance apportée par tel ou tel temps qui serait perdue si on devait se conformer scrupuleusement à la règle. Par exemple, au paragraphe 1156, Grévisse cite Bergson :

> Il me semble que si, quelque part, elle *devrait* se sentir chez elle et évoluer à son aise, c'est parmi les choses de l'esprit.

Dans mon exemple, je pense qu'on introduit une légère différence de sens en remplaçant *réussit* par *réussissait* ou *pourrait* par *pourra*, l'indicatif traduisant dans chaque cas une plus grande probabilité de réalisation de la condition dans l'esprit du locuteur. Dans le cas de *pourrait*, c'est tout à fait spécifique à ce verbe-là et à quelques autres verbes modaux (*devrait*, *ne saurait*, etc.); il ne me viendrait pas à l'esprit de dire « S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, il aurait un problème ».

Je ne trouve toutefois aucun exemple parallèle au mien dans le Grévisse (avec un conditionnel à valeur particulière dans la principale). Je me demande donc si la question de l'admissibilité de phrases de cette sorte est traitée quelque part dans une grammaire sérieuse. Les **traitements simplistes** qui n'évoqueraient pas les cas d'exception comme ceux du Grévisse ne m'intéressent pas.

Comment: Voir dans  l'ouvrage *La pratique du style: Simplicité, précision, harmonie* [le chapitre « Concordance des temps »](https://books.google.fr/books?id=d4wVEIwHTHwC&pg=PA77&hl=fr&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q=concordance&f=false) qui cite à la fois Grevisse et Ferdinand Brunot (pp 27- 30).

Answer (score 2):

La phrase indiquée est **tout à fait correcte sur le plan grammatical**. Elle indique une conséquence hypothétique, si la condition est vérifiée, et avec un **double niveau hypothétique**: *conditionnel* + *pouvoir*:

> S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, cela pourrait poser problème.

Avec la formule suivante, c'est **un peu plus sûr**, mais reste hypothétique (possible), à cause du verbe pouvoir.

> S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, cela pourra poser problème.

La forme suivante serait **encore plus sûre**, sans le verbe pouvoir:

> S'il ne réussit pas à la joindre, cela posera problème.

Et si on sait que la condition sera vérifié, on peut dire:

> Comme il ne réussira pas à la joindre, cela posera problème.

**En espérant que cela vous aide et vous *intéresse* !**